# Average Count of Genres per Movie for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Stumbled into a problem using an IMBd dataset that I can't seem to figure out the answer to. The question is:

> Create a table that contains the average count of genres per movie for
>   each genre

We have two tables: Movies: id, name; Genres: id (movieId), genre

Movies:

```
id,name
1,Toy Story
2,Jumanji
3,Grumpier Old Men
4,Waiting to Exhale
5,Father of the Bride Part II
6,Heat
```

Genres:

```
id,genre
1,Animation
1,Children's
1,Comedy
2,Adventure
2,Children's
2,Fantasy
3,Comedy
3,Romance
4,Comedy
4,Drama
5,Comedy
6,Action
6,Crime
6,Thriller
```

I maybe interpreting the question incorrectly, but shouldn't the output be 3 columns: genre, movie, and count?

My answer would start along the lines of:

```
SELECT genre, name, AVG(COUNT(*)) FROM movies
JOIN genres ON genres.id=movies.id
GROUP BY name;
```

Any ideas on how you would interpret the question and answer?

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query shouldn't even run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would start with the number of genres per movie:

```
select id, count(*) as num_genres
from genres g
group by id
```

Then, I would "attach" this information to the genres information.  And aggregate and average:

```
select g.genre, avg(m.num_genres)
from genres g join
     (select id, count(*) as num_genres
      from genres g
      group by id
     ) m
     on g.id = m.id
group by g.genre;
```

Comment: Doesn't having two Select statements seem excessive here?

Comment: @Ryan . . . It appears to solve the problem.  It could use a window function instead of you are using MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon first number of genres per movie

```
select id, count(*) as num_genres
from genres g
group by id
```

But the average of genres per movies should be

```
SELECT AVG(num_generes)
FROM (
      SELECT id, count(*) as num_genres
      FROM genres g
      GROUP BY id
      ) t
```

Comment: . . "for each genre".